# Is there a way to replace a building as an atomic operation?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I have a situation where I want to change some tiles into insulated tiles. As far as I know, the only method of doing this is to first deconstruct the tile, and then construct the insulated tile.

Is there a way to do this in one operation? I want to avoid waiting for the deconstruction, but my primary goal is to keep the time when there is no tile there as short as possible.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Oni]

I don't remember if I activated a specific option for it, But I can replace standard tile with insulated tile simply by building over it.

This does not work for replacing a background tile with a front-ground one.
It also works if you want to change the material but building the same tile.
There is some priority rules : As far I remember, you can build a tile over (and replacing) a ladder, but not the other way around,